# Property 'cause' does not exist on type 'Error' in new Vue 3 project

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I created a new Vue app via `npm init vue@latest` with the following setup

[image]

I replaced the content of the *App.vue* file with

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const e = new Error("something failed");

console.log(e.cause);
</script>
```

I get the following error

> Property 'cause' does not exist on type 'Error'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the 'lib' compiler option to 'es2022' or later.ts(2550)

Based on [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/cause) the cause property should exist. I added `"lib": ["ESNext"],` to *tsconfig.vitest.json*, *tsconfig.config.json* and *tsconfig.app.json* ( I don't know which one needs it ). Then I get the error

> Cannot find name 'console'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the 'lib' compiler option to include 'dom'.ts(2584)

so I add it too and it seems to be fine now. It feels wrong to me since this already is a web project and I don't think the basic setup is lacking essential features...

**So are there any better solutions for this?**

I also tried to set this field inside the *tsconfig.json* file like so

```
{
  "files": [],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["ESNext", "DOM"],
  },
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.config.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.vitest.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

but this didn't work, then `cause` does not exist on type `Error` again.

---

I just want to have access to the `cause` property of `Error` inside a new Vue project :)

Comment: If you log out `new Error()` you'll see it's an empty object. So `cause` does not exist in Error and you're trying to access an inexisted key.

Comment: This is not a runtime error. When changing the playground to ESNext this works https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/MYewdgzgLgBAHjAvDMBTA7jAogJxyHACgEoBuAKHNEhABtUA6WkAc0LgeAEMBXCVMkA

Comment: Still throws an empty object.

Comment: it logs undefined

Comment: @Amini would you mind explaining how to get access to the cause prop in new Vue projects? ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/cause )

Answer (score 0):

You need to first set an `cause`  for the error and later you can console log it.

```js
const myError = new Error('Databse status:503')

myError.cause = 'Database failed to connect!'

console.log(myError.cause)
```

Comment: yes, I do know that. But should I set the compiler options everywhere to `"lib": ["ESNext", "DOM"],` ?